# Different way to write this

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, python-requests

I have a script that will sometimes catch a `ChunckedEncodingError` while using the `requests` package in python.

I've successfully fixed the issue by doing the following:

```
try:
    _, status, html_data, _ = lib.core.common.get_page(url, agent=agent, proxy=proxy)
except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
    lib.core.settings.logger.warning(lib.core.settings.set_color(
        "encoding seems to be messed up, trying the request again...", level=30
    ))
    try:
        _, status, html_data, _ = lib.core.common.get_page(url, agent=agent, proxy=proxy)
    except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
        lib.core.settings.logger.error(lib.core.settings.set_color(
            "encoding is unable to be fixed from a retry, skipping...", level=40
        ))
        return False, None
except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL:
    url = "http://{}".format(url)
    _, status, html_data, _ = lib.core.common.get_page(url, agent=agent, proxy=proxy)
```

Now this works and all, but I don't really like the whole `try` inside an `except` block, is there another way I could write this to be more pythonic and readable?

---

From the provided answer, I was able to come up with this:

```
retry_flags = 3
auto_assign = "http://{}"
url_verification = re.compile(r"http(s)?", re.I)

if url_verification.search(url) is None:
    lib.core.settings.logger.warning(lib.core.settings.set_color(
        "protocol missing from URL, automatically assigning protocol...", level=30
    ))
    url = auto_assign.format(url)

while retry_flags > 0:
    try:
        _, status, html_data, _ = lib.core.common.get_page(url, agent=agent, proxy=proxy)
    except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
        lib.core.settings.logger.warning(lib.core.settings.set_color(
            "encoding seems to be messed up, retrying request...", level=30
        ))
        retry_flags -= 1
return False, None
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Could a `finally` call come in handy here?

Comment: try-except in a loop and break on success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while loop is clear and well structured by quite a few linguistic standards.

```
def get_url_wrapper(url, agent, proxy):
    flag = 3

    while flag > 0:
        try:
           _, status, html_data, _ = lib.core.common.get_page(url, agent=agent, proxy=proxy)
           return status, html_data
        except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL:
            # This is a case of invalid structure. Don't modify flag
            url = "http://{}".format(url)
        except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
            lib.core.settings.logger.error(lib.core.settings.set_color(
                "encoding is unable to be fixed from a retry, skipping...", level=40
            ))
            # this is an actual error, decrement flag.
            flag -= 1

    return False, None
```

Comment: So instead of catching the `InvalidURL` exception, I added a simple regex (`re.compile(r"http(s)?", re.I).search(url)`) and added the protocol to it (if none) before connecting, from there I used your while loop idea and it seems to be working well, thank you.